# Error al comparar nombre de dos contactos en un arraylist agenda_telefono

Tags: java, arraylist

estoy programando una agenda telefonica usando arrayList. Quiero comparar los nombres e imprimir que no se puede agregar el contacto a la agenda si se repiten. Me salta este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at recursos.agenda_telefonica.aniadirContacto(agenda_telefonica.java:15)
    at principal.principal.main(principal.java:20).
```

Les dejo el código:

```
public class Contacto {

    private String nombre;
    private int numero;

    public Contacto(String nombre, int numero) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }


}
```

Clase agenda_telefonica:

```
package recursos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class agenda_telefonica {

    private final static int TAMANIO = 10;   
    ArrayList <Contacto> listatel = new ArrayList <Contacto>();
    Contacto contacto;

    public void aniadirContacto(Contacto c){ 
            listatel = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if(c.getNombre().equals(listatel.get(i).getNombre())){
                    System.out.println("No se puede agregar");
                }else{
                    listatel.add(c);
                }

        }
    }        
    public void existeContacto(Contacto c){
        if(listatel.contains(c)){
            System.out.println("Este contacto ya existe");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Este contacto no existe");
        }             
    }
    public void buscaContacto(String nombre){
        for (int i = 0; i < listatel.size(); i++) {
            if(nombre.equals(listatel.get(i).getNombre())){
                System.out.println(listatel.get(i).getNumero());
            }
        }
    }
    public void eliminarContacto(Contacto c){
        listatel.remove(c);

        if(!listatel.contains(c)){
            System.out.println("Se ha eliminado correctamente");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No se ha eliminado");
        }
    }
    public void agendaLlena(){
        if(listatel.size()>=10){
            System.out.println("Agenda llena");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Lugar disponible");
        }
    }
    public void huecosLibres(){
        int hueco_libre = agenda_telefonica.TAMANIO - listatel.size();
        System.out.println(hueco_libre);
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Contacto c01 = new Contacto("carlos", 1555750721);
        Contacto c02 = new Contacto("pablo", 1555750811);
        Contacto c03 = new Contacto("ezequiel", 1567820721);
        Contacto c04 = new Contacto("nati", 1553340721);
        Contacto c05 = new Contacto("carlos", 1555712421);

        agenda_telefonica agenda = new agenda_telefonica();

        agenda.aniadirContacto(c01);
        agenda.aniadirContacto(c02);
        agenda.aniadirContacto(c03);
        agenda.aniadirContacto(c04);
aca deberia darme el mensaje "No se puede agregar"
        agenda.aniadirContacto(c05);

        agenda.buscaContacto("pablo");
        System.out.println(c01.getNombre());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un problema en el ciclo de vida de tu aplicación. No puedes iniciar la lista `listatel = new ArrayList();` de contactos cada vez que vas a añadir un contacto ya que esto borrara los que ya hayas agregado en esa lista. Ya estás inicializando la lista cuando la declaras :

```
ArrayList <Contacto> listatel = new ArrayList <Contacto>();
```

Lo que hace que no sea necesario volver a instanciarla en otro método. el error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` hace referencia a que cuando intentas comparar tu lista en el for, no tiene nada en la posición i por lo que hace referencia a que tu lista está VACÍA y mi solución es la siguiente:

```
Boolean var = true;
 for (int i = 0; i < listatel.size(); i++) {
            if(c.getNombre().equals(listatel.get(i).getNombre())){
                var = false
            }
    }

if(var){
  listatel.add(c);
}else{
  System.out.println("No se puede agregar");
 }
```

Debes decirle al for que las veces que se vaya a repetir sea el mismo numero de contactos que tienes en tu lista, ya que esto hará que si tu lista está vacía nunca entre al for. Y debes añadir el contacto fuera de el for por que si dejas el método lista.add dentro del for, añadirá éste contacto las veces que se itere el for, es decir puede añadirlo 1 vez a las lista como puede añadirlo 10.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes este método:

```
public void aniadirContacto(Contacto c){ 
    listatel = new ArrayList();                   //Creas un ArrayList vacío SIEMPRE
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                // asumes que tiene 10 elementos
        if(c.getNombre().equals(listatel.get(i).getNombre())){
            System.out.println("No se puede agregar");
        }else{
             listatel.add(c);
        }

    }
}
```

Puesto que ese ArrayList está vacío, no existe ni siquiera la posición 0. Al intentar acceder a dicha posición, tienes esa IndexOutOfBoundsException (traducida significa *Excepción: Índice fuera de rango*).

La forma correcta de implementarlo sería

```
public void aniadirContacto(Contacto c){ 
    if (listatel ==null) {
        listatel = new ArrayList();  //Creas un ArrayList vacío si no hay uno
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listatel.size(); i++) {                
        if(c.getNombre().equals(listatel.get(i).getNombre())){
            System.out.println("No se puede agregar");
        }else{
             listatel.add(c);
        }

    }
}
```